# Language history: origin of variable 'it' in read-eval-print loop?

Tags: programming-languages, history, interpreter

Some interactive systems, including Standard ML of New Jersey and GHC, offer an interactive toplevel loop where you can type expressions and see results.  A nice little convenience is that the result of the most recent expression is bound to the variable `it`.  Here's an example from GHCi:

```
Prelude> 3 + 5
8
Prelude> it
8
Prelude> 2 * it
16
Prelude> it + 1
17
```

I'm trying to trace the origin of this convention.  Can anyone provide examples of other interactive systems that have used similar conventions?  And date them if possible?

Comment: Just a guess, but it may stand for "interactive", but "in" is a reserved word.

Comment: "it" -- "the thing" (result in this case)

Comment: Can we Community Wiki this? It would be interesting to see the number of different ways this is exposed in various REPLs.

Comment: Isn't that essentially the concept of the accumulator handed up from the CPU level into the programming language?

Answer (score 1):

Ruby provides the same convenience variable as `_`:

```
>> 3 + 5
=> 8
>> _
=> 8
>> 2 * _
=> 16
>> _ + 1
=> 17
```

Interestingly, the global variable `$_` is also available: it's the last input read from `gets` or `readline`.

Answer (score 1):

Many common lisps use '*' to denote previous results. EG '*' is the last result, '**' is the result before last, etc:

```
* 5
5
* 6
6
* 7
7
* (+ * ** ***)
18
```

Python has '_' which is last result:

```
>>> 5
5
>>> _
5
```

Erlang has a function 'v()':

```
1> 5.
5
2> 6.
6
3> 7.
7
4> v(1) + v(2) + v(3).
18
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a REPL, but hypertalk (the language of hypercard) allowed "it" in some contexts.  I'm not sure of the exact usage case, as I never used hypercard, but it appears to be a similar idea.  This dates it to 1986 or so.

Comment: It was pretty much a convention followed by some commands to provide a second return value. E.g. the 'answer' and 'ask' commands (which show a dialog with buttons resp. a text field) provided the button clicked/text entered in a local variable named "it". There was also a 'get' command that was simply a shorthand for getting an expression's result into the 'it' variable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the first instance of a REPL with history list functionality was BBN LISP, ca. 1972.

"In BBN-LISP, each input typed by the user, and the value of the corresponding operation, are automatically stored by the p.a. on a global data structure called the history list."  I could not find any documentation on how to actually access those values, only on how to repeat previous events using REDO. (See http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/LISP/interlisp/Teitelman-FCJJ1972.pdf)

Nor could I find any single keyword for accessing the last history value in its successor Interlisp, possibly due to lack of Google-Fu.

Comment: Thanks; lots of tools have used a history list, including shells and debuggers.  But asking some old LISPers would be good.